# Wine game fails to run and says that it requires 256 colors?

Tags: wine

I am trying to run [Yobi's Basic Spelling Tricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling_Jungle) under Wine but I'm getting this error message:

> Basic Spelling Tricks CD requires support for 256 colors.

This is a game originally made for Windows 3.1 so it's a win16 game, if that makes a difference. It works fine under DOSBox (DOS > Win 3.11 > Game) but it runs too slowly on the netbook I'm trying to setup for old DOS games. I'm hoping that running it under Wine will speed things up, if I can get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is addressed on the [Wine wiki](https://wiki.winehq.org/256_Color_Mode); the recommended workaround is to use [Xephyr](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Xephyr/), starting a secondary 8-bit X server inside your main X server:

```
Xephyr :1 -ac -screen 800x600x8 &
DISPLAY=:1 xterm &
```

This will start `xterm` inside the new display; you can then start a window manager and your Windows program (from the new `xterm`):

```
metacity &
```

(assuming your window manager is Metacity), and then whatever you need to run your program using Wine.

Comment: I'm accepting this  because it does answer the question. However, while it does get the game to run, Wine fails to display any graphics (sound and mouse work and the game is actually running). This is probably a failure of Wine itself.